# PowerShell Extract text between two strings with -Tail and -Wait

Tags: powershell, find, extract, getcontent

I have a text file with a large number of log messages.
I want to extract the messages between two string patterns. I want the extracted message to appear as it is in the text file.

I tried the following methods. It works, but doesn't support Get-Content's -Wait and -Tail options. Also, the extracted results are displayed in one line, but not like the text file. Inputs are welcome :-)

**Sample Code**

```
function GetTextBetweenTwoStrings($startPattern, $endPattern, $filePath){

    # Get content from the input file
    $fileContent = Get-Content $filePath

    # Regular expression (Regex) of the given start and end patterns
    $pattern = "$startPattern(.*?)$endPattern"

    # Perform the Regex opperation
    $result = [regex]::Match($fileContent,$pattern).Value

    # Finally return the result to the caller
    return $result
}

# Clear the screen
Clear-Host

$input = "THE-LOG-FILE.log"
$startPattern = 'START-OF-PATTERN'
$endPattern = 'END-OF-PATTERN'

# Call the function
GetTextBetweenTwoStrings -startPattern $startPattern -endPattern $endPattern -filePath $input
```

**Improved script based on Theo's answer.**
The following points need to be improved:

1. The beginning and end of the output is somehow trimmed despite I adjusted the buffer size in the script.
2. How to wrap each matched result into START and END string?
3. Still I could not figure out how to use the `-Wait` and `-Tail` options

**Updated Script**

```
# Clear the screen
Clear-Host

# Adjust the buffer size of the window
$bw = 10000
$bh = 300000
if ($host.name -eq 'ConsoleHost') # or -notmatch 'ISE'
{
  [console]::bufferwidth = $bw
  [console]::bufferheight = $bh
}
else
{
    $pshost = get-host
    $pswindow = $pshost.ui.rawui
    $newsize = $pswindow.buffersize
    $newsize.height = $bh
    $newsize.width = $bw
    $pswindow.buffersize = $newsize
}


function Get-TextBetweenTwoStrings ([string]$startPattern, [string]$endPattern, [string]$filePath){
    # Get content from the input file
    $fileContent = Get-Content -Path $filePath -Raw
    # Regular expression (Regex) of the given start and end patterns
    $pattern = '(?is){0}(.*?){1}' -f [regex]::Escape($startPattern), [regex]::Escape($endPattern)
    # Perform the Regex operation and output
    [regex]::Match($fileContent,$pattern).Groups[1].Value
}

# Input file path
 $inputFile = "THE-LOG-FILE.log"

# The patterns
$startPattern = 'START-OF-PATTERN'
$endPattern = 'END-OF-PATTERN'


Get-TextBetweenTwoStrings -startPattern $startPattern -endPattern $endPattern -filePath $inputFile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to perform *streaming* processing of your [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) call, in a *pipeline*, such as with [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object), if you want to process lines *as they're being read*.

  - This is a must if you're using `Get-Content -Wait`, because such a call doesn't terminate by itself (it keeps waiting for new lines to be added to the file, indefinitely), but inside a pipeline its output can be processed *as it is being received*, even before the command terminates.
- You're trying to match *across multiple lines*, which with `Get-Content` output would only work if you used the `-Raw` switch - by default, `Get-Content` reads its input file(s) *line by line*.

  - However, `-Raw` is incompatible with `-Wait`.
  - Therefore, you  must stick with *line-by-line processing*, which requires that you match the start and end patterns *separately*, and keep track of when you're processing lines *between* those two patterns.

Here's a proof of concept, but note the following:

- `-Tail 100` is hard-coded - adjust as needed or make it another parameter.
- The use of `-Wait` means that the function will run indefinitely - waiting for new lines to be added to `$filePath` - so you'll need to use <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to stop it.

  - While you can use a `Get-TextBetweenTwoStrings` call itself in a pipeline for object-by-object processing, *assigning its result to a variable (`$result = ...`) won't work* when terminating with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, because this method of termination also aborts the assignment operation.
  - To work around this limitation, the function below is defined as an [*advanced* function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced), which automatically enables support for the [common `-OutVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-outvariable), which *is* populated even in the event of termination with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>; your sample call would then look as follows (as Theo notes, don't use the automatic `$input` variable as a custom variable):

    ```sh
    # Look for blocks of interest in the input file, indefinitely,
    # and output them as they're being found.
    # After termination with Ctrl-C, $result will also contain the blocks
    # found, if any.
    Get-TextBetweenTwoStrings -OutVariable result -startPattern $startPattern -endPattern $endPattern -filePath $inputFile
    ```
- Per your feedback you want the block of lines to encompass the *full lines* on which the start and end patterns match, so the regexes below are enclosed in `.*`
- The word *pattern* in your `$startPattern` and `$endPattern` parameters is a bit ambiguous in that it suggests that they themselves are *regexes* that can therefore be used as-is or embedded as-is in a larger regex on the RHS of the [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator.
  However, in the solution below I am assuming that they are be treated as *literal* strings, which is why they are escaped with [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape); simply omit these calls if these parameters are indeed regexes themselves; i.e.:

  ```sh
  $startRegex = '.*' + $startPattern + '.*'
  $endRegex = '.*' + $endPattern + '.*'
  ```
- The solution assumes there is no overlap between blocks and that, in a given block, the start and end patterns are on separate lines.
- Each block found is output as a single, multi-line string, using LF (`` "`n" ``) as the newline character; if you want a CRLF newline sequences instead, use `` "`r`n" ``; for the platform-native newline format (CRLF on Windows, LF on Unix-like platforms), use `[Environment]::NewLine`.

```sh
# Note the use of "-" after "Get", to adhere to PowerShell's
# "<Verb>-<Noun>" naming convention.
function Get-TextBetweenTwoStrings {

  # Make the function an advanced one, so that it supports the 
  # -OutVariable common parameter.
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    $startPattern, 
    $endPattern, 
    $filePath
  )

  # Note: If $startPattern and $endPattern are themselves
  #       regexes, omit the [regex]::Escape() calls.
  $startRegex = '.*' + [regex]::Escape($startPattern) + '.*'
  $endRegex = '.*' + [regex]::Escape($endPattern) + '.*'

  $inBlock = $false
  $block = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()

  Get-Content -Tail 100 -Wait $filePath | ForEach-Object {
    if ($inBlock) {
      if ($_ -match $endRegex) {
        $block.Add($Matches[0])
        # Output the block of lines as a single, multi-line string
        $block -join "`n"
        $inBlock = $false; $block.Clear()       
      }
      else {
        $block.Add($_)
      }
    }
    elseif ($_ -match $startRegex) {
      $inBlock = $true
      $block.Add($Matches[0])
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: thank you for the quick feedback.
I appended `.*` and prepend `.*?` into the `$startPattern` and `$endPattern` but complete line for the `$endPattern` is not shown in the output.
Another issue is that it captures and shows only the first match and after that it does not show any matches in the output.

Comment: Also, when I use `ctrl + c` to terminate the script, in the status bar I only the `stopping` and no more output in the console. FYI, I am using `PowerShell ISE`.

Comment: @Sherzad Re only capturing the first match: that was an oversight on my part, sorry: `$inBlock` needs to be reset to `$false` after finding the end pattern - please see my update, which also uses updated regexes to capture the _full_ lines. As for Ctrl-C: the execution environment (console vs. ISE) shouldn't matter; I've just tried in the ISE, and it works as intended.

Comment: @Sherzad As an aside: The ISE: It is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 6+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Comment: @Sherzad, I've switched to using `[regex]::Escape()`, and added some more clarifications. From what I can tell, everything works as intended now, both in a regular console window and in the ISE. Again, note that you can NOT do `$result = Get-TextBetweenTwoStrings ...` and must use `Get-TextBetweenTwoStrings -OutVariable result ...` instead.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not use `$input` as self-defined variable name, because this is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#input).

Then, you are reading the file as a string **array**, where you would rather read is as a single, multiline string. For that append switch `-Raw` to the Get-Content call.

The regex you are creating does not allow fgor regex special characters in the start- and end patterns you give, so it I would suggest using `[regex]::Escape()` on these patterns when creating the regex string.

While your regex does use a group capturing sequence inside the brackets, you are not using that when it comes to getting the value you seek.

Finally, I would recommend using PowerShell naming convention (Verb-Noun) for the function name

Try

```
function Get-TextBetweenTwoStrings ([string]$startPattern, [string]$endPattern, [string]$filePath){
    # Get content from the input file
    $fileContent = Get-Content -Path $filePath -Raw
    # Regular expression (Regex) of the given start and end patterns
    $pattern = '(?is){0}(.*?){1}' -f [regex]::Escape($startPattern), [regex]::Escape($endPattern)
    # Perform the Regex operation and output
    [regex]::Match($fileContent,$pattern).Groups[1].Value
}

$inputFile    = "D:\Test\THE-LOG-FILE.log"
$startPattern = 'START-OF-PATTERN'
$endPattern   = 'END-OF-PATTERN'

Get-TextBetweenTwoStrings -startPattern $startPattern -endPattern $endPattern -filePath $inputFile
```

Would result in something like:

```
blahblah
more lines here
```

<sup>The `(?is)` makes the regex case-insensitive and have the dot match linebreaks as well</sup>

---

Nice to see you're using my version of the `Get-TextBetweenTwoStrings` function, however I believe you are mistaking the output in the console to output as in a dedicated text editor. In the console, too long lines will be truncated, whereas in a text editor like notepad, you can choose to wrap long lines or have a horizontal scrollbar.

If you simply append

```
| Set-Content -Path 'X:\wherever\theoutput.txt'
```

to the `Get-TextBetweenTwoStrings ..` call, you will find the lines are **NOT** truncated when you open it in Word or notepad for instance.

In fact, you can have that line folowed by

```
notepad 'X:\wherever\theoutput.txt'
```

to have notepad open that file straight away.

Comment: thanks for your inputs and please see my edited question for the existing issues.

Comment: @Sherzad, Theo's answer has good advice in general, but if you want to use `-Wait` , you _must_ use _line-by-line_ processing; multi-line matching with `-Raw` is then not an option.

Comment: @Sherzad Please see my edit.

Comment: @Theo, how to include the start and end patterns in the output as well, any idea? Even though this is the `</MSG></LOG>` value for the `$endpattern`, nothing in the output. Of course, `</MSG></LOG>` is not at the beginning of a line.

Comment: @Sherzad This looks more a XML file than a plain-text log file. Is that the case here? XML should not be processed like this and needs a different approach.

Comment: @Sherzad If you question indeed is how to extract the text from an XML node, I'd suggest you post a new question for that since this one has been answered already. Do not forget to include a representable example of the file in that new question.